# Why is postgres not using a BTree index for a like 'CONSTANT_PREFIX_%' criteria?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a B-Tree index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_test_report_accession on test_report (accession);
```

I run the following query with explain :

```
"QUERY PLAN"
"Seq Scan on public.test_report r  (cost=0.00..705829.12 rows=30694 width=1140) (actual time=0.143..6253.818 rows=11094 loops=1)"
"  Output: detected_transcript_translation_id, peptide_spectrum_match_id, accession, peptide, modified_sequence, var_mod, spectrum_title, spectrum_file, confidence, mz, retention_time, precursor_mz_error_ppm, sample_name, transcript, gene_symbol, prot_seq, ref_based_location, external_identifier, experiment_name, report_filename, line_number, experiment_path"
"  Filter: (r.accession ~~ 'IP_%'::text)"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 4296116"
"Planning time: 1.331 ms"
"Execution time: 6255.560 ms"
```

It seems to think that there are only 30694 rows in the table, and decides not to use the index. Given that the  like wildcard is a suffix, I see no reason to not use the index...

The row count is :

```
SELECT count(*) from test_report r;
4307210
```

there number of matching rows is quite smaller :

```
SELECT count(*) from test_report r WHERE r.accession like 'IP_%';
11094
```

#### Notes:

- Postgres version is 9.4

Comment: Please show the output of `explain (analyze, verbose)`. Also: what is your exact Postgres version? Older versions required `text_pattern_ops` for the `create index`

Comment: @a_horse: Has something changed? As far as I'm aware, `text_pattern_ops` is still necessary for Unicode-collated fields.

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, I augmented the verbosity of the explain and added the pg version (9.4) as you suggested

Answer (score 6):

Under many collations, words that share the same prefix might not occur next to each other in sort order.  [See here](https://superuser.com/questions/227925/in-utf-8-collation-why-11-is-less-then-1) for example.  That means an index with those collations cannot be used effectively to fulfill a prefix query.

Unless your database collation is "C", then your default indexes will not be usable for prefix searching.  You can manually specify a collation or an operator class to use in the index which will support it:

```
create index on foobar (x collate "C");
```

or

```
create index on foobar (x text_pattern_ops);
```

I just create all my databases with the "C" collation (which you can do even if you need to use the `UTF8` encoding).  Some people don't like the way it sorts, but that is mostly due to case sensitivity.  No one has ever complained to me "Hey, you need to sort by en_US.UTF-8 collations rules".  That is probably because almost no one knows what those rules are.